# trying to make an event handler to dispose of stagewebview when back is pressed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

how can i add an event handler to my stagewebview so that it disposes itself when the back button on android phones or the popview button on my actionbar is pressed? here's what i have so far....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:ns1="*"
    title="{data.image}"
    creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        public var webView:StageWebView=new StageWebView();
        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            webView.stage=this.stage;
            webView.viewPort=new Rectangle(0,50,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            var fPath:String=new File(new File("app:/assets/chapter1images/image1.html").nativePath).url;
            webView.loadURL(fPath);
        }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: I basically want the finished product to resemble android's webView when i'm done....any recommendations?

Comment: This site will provide you with an answer: http://johncblandii.com/2011/08/flex-mobile-stagewebview-removal.html#comment-419214231